# Ionic v3 - Convert local image to base64

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I need to use an image taken with Camera and/or Library and send it to Firebase, I made use of the following native plugins in order:

- [Camera](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/)/[ImagePicker](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/image-picker/);
- [Crop](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/crop);
- [Base64](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64);

After that I use the ["putString" function of angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md) and works perfectly on Android, but in IOS the execution for the Base64 plugin, either with camera image or Bibioteca does not return any error.

I tried the common conversion by JS but it is not allowed by CORS, is there any alternative to CORD64 base64 plugin?

Comment: Can you share your current implementation? Also the Camera plugin has config to save image as base64 data string - why would you need base64 plugin?

Comment: I can not currently share, the Camera plugin saved in FILE_URI, so I kept it because I need it and the ImagePicker that responds to the image with the path in an Array, as the Crop I use after those generates the image also as FILE_URI nothing would change, I need to do the conversion after going through Crop